# Is it Possible to Cache the Result of my Custom ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an MVC website that uses AD authentication to display data for users that are also CRM 2011.  The CRM Rights of the user are determined by their role in CRM, so currently the `OnActionExecuting` method gets the executing user's domain name, and queries CRM for their role.  If they don't have a valid role, an invalid rights view is instead returned.

The call to CRM is slow and can get expensive if it has to happen for every request.  I can see in the [MVC 3 release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#RTM-BC) that the filters are aggressively cached, but wasn't quite sure what that meant for me.

I'd like to be able to cache the rights of the user based on their domain name, but it sounds like that may already be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are [referring to following statement](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#RTM-BC), I think you have understood this point wrong:

> In ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are cached more aggressively. Therefore,
>   any custom action filters which improperly store instance state might
>   be broken.

This does not mean, that the result of the filter is cached. It means that the filter itself will be cached and will be reused for multiple requests. It is comparable with CRM Plugins. You should not track state in it or if you do, you have to be careful to not enter the joys of concurrency.

In your case I would use for example [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) to cache the roles/privileges of the user in memory for a period of time.

Comment: So a single ActionFilterAttribute object may be created and used by multiple requests by different users?

Comment: I'm thinking that the use of a MemoryCache would not be good for any user specific data when dealing with webfarms.  You could make 6 different requests and hit 6 different servers and all 6 would have to populate the cache.  Really I need to be using the Session since they'd be shared (assuming it's configured that way) among all servers on the farm.

Comment: @Daryl that's why I wrote _for example_. If you have distributed servers, you have to use a distributed cache like [AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx), Redis, memcached,... . I would not necessarily put this information into the session